# Is there a solution for $y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + \sinh^{-1}(y) = x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a closed form solution for $y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + \sinh^{-1}(y) = x$?

I would like to invert the arc length of a parabola so I can parameterize it with a constant speed.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anybody construct a natural parametrization of the parabola, or even an intrinsic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: inverse hyperbolic functions can be expressed in [terms of logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms):

$$y+\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + \sinh^{-1}(y) = y+\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + \log(y + \sqrt{y^2+1})= z + log(z) = x$$

<s>where $z = y + \sqrt{y^2+1}$ 
The last equation can be expressed in a closed form only by using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)</s>

Edited: Sorry, I misread the first term (are you sure you got it right?). This turns the equation almost hopeless to find a closed form solution.

Comment: Yes, it's a simplified version of $\int \sqrt{4x^2 + 1}\ dx$. ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%284y%5E2+%2B+1%29))