# Explicit nontrivial examples of arc length parametrization

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, parametric, arc-length

For pedagogical purposes (and for some numerical experiments) I was looking for some nontrivial explicit (i.e. closed-form) examples of arclength parametrized curves. I know that arclength parametrization always exists for a regular curve, but it seems that the general consensus is that trying to compute this explicitly is generally madness.

Of course any straight line and circular arc can be explicitly parametrized this way, but I was wondering if there are any other known nontrivial examples (especially ones with nonconstant curvature)?

Comment: How about the Archimedean spiral? It has non trivial curvature and nice arc length expression (well it's closed form but perhaps its inverse still isn't).

Comment: As it happens, I had actually started thinking about this precisely because I was using the Archimedean spiral to test some ideas about some code. Turned out I needed to parametrize it in terms of arclength, and have unfortunately been unable to find such a closed form expression. So if you know an expression for that one, I'd be super happy to see it!

Comment: google Archimedean spiral arc length should give what you want. I'm not sure though if it's still any help when the inverse is not in closed form.

Comment: I'm looking for the inverse in closed form. Otherwise I won't be able to parametrize the spiral in terms of arclength. Looking through stack exchange it seems most answerers don't believe there is a closed form. This is the closest I've found: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81636/how-to-place-objects-equidistantly-on-an-archimedean-spiral

Comment: You might consider curves with simple [intrinsic equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CesaroEquation.html).

Answer (score 5):

After some time I came across a few more examples to add to the list.

---

The [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral),
$$
\alpha(t) = (e^t\cos t, e^t\sin t)
$$
which has $\|\alpha'(t)\|=\sqrt{2}\,e^t$ and so has arc length
$$
s = \int_0^t \|\alpha'(u)\|\,\mathrm{d}u =\int_0^t \sqrt{2}\,e^u \,\mathrm{d}u = \sqrt{2}\,(e^t-1)
$$
and so $t=\ln\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)$ which let's us reparametrize the curve as
$$
\tilde\alpha(s)=\left( \left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)\cos\left(\ln\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)\right), \left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)\sin\left(\ln\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right) \right)\right)
$$

---

The [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix),
$$
\beta(t) = (a\cos t, a\sin t, bt)
$$
which has $\|\beta'(t)\| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and so has arc length
$$
s = \int_0^t \|\beta'(u)\|\,\mathrm{d}u\int_0^t \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\,\mathrm{d}u = t\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$
and so $t=\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ which let's us reparametrize the curve as
$$
\tilde{\beta}(s) = \left( a\cos\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right), a\sin\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right), \frac{bs}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)
$$

---

A helix-like curve inside in a [flat torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus),
$$
\gamma(t) = (a\cos At, a\sin At, b\cos Bt, b\sin Bt)
$$
which has $\|\gamma'(t)\|=\sqrt{a^2A^2+b^2B^2}$ and so has arc length
$$
s = \int_0^t \|\gamma'(u)\|\,\mathrm{d}u\int_0^t \sqrt{a^2A^2+b^2B^2}\,\mathrm{d}u = t\sqrt{a^2A^2+b^2B^2}
$$
and so $t=\frac{s}{C}$ where $C = \sqrt{a^2A^2+b^2B^2}$. This let's us reparametrize the curve as
$$
\tilde\gamma(s)=\left( a\cos\frac{As}{C}, a\sin\frac{As}{C},b\cos\frac{Bs}{C},b\sin\frac{Bs}{C}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

A nice simple one is [Neile's parabola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemicubicalParabola.html),
$$ y = \frac{2}{3}ax^{3/2}. $$
One finds $dy/dx = a\sqrt{x}$, so the arc-length integral is
$$ \int_0^X \sqrt{1+a^2x} \, dx = \frac{2}{3a^2}\left((1+a^2X)^{3/2}-1 \right). $$

---

One can also do the ordinary parabola,
$$ x=at^2 \qquad y=2at, $$
which has arc-length integral
$$ \int_0^T 2a\sqrt{1+t^2} \, dt = aT\sqrt{1+T^2} +a \arg\sinh{T}, $$
which is all but the same as the Archimedes' spiral case. This is likely only invertible by reversion of series, which will only work up to one of the singularities on the right.

---

Another simple one is the [tractrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html), which has parametric equations
$$ x = a(t-\tanh{t}), \qquad y=a\operatorname{sech}{t}, $$
and the arc-length is given by
$$ \int_0^T a\tanh{t} \, dt = a\log{\cosh{T}}, $$
which is easy to invert.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across one this morning at [Area of the surface from curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266891/area-of-the-surface-from-curve/2267552#2267552).

If $y=\cosh(4x)/4, x\in [-1,1]$, then

$$L=\int ds=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\ dx=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\sinh^2(4x)}\ dx=\int_{-1}^1 \cosh(4x)\ dx=\frac{\sinh(4)}{2}$$

Here's another example, the parabola $y=1-x^2, x\in [-1,1]$

$$L=\int ds=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\ dx=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+4x^2}\ dx=\sqrt{5}+\frac{\sinh^{-1}(2)}{2}$$

And here's a parametric form in the complex plane,

$$
z=\cos^3(t)+i\sin^3(t), t\in [0,\pi/2]\\
s=\int|\dot z|dt\\
\dot z=3[-\cos^2(t)\sin(t)+i\sin^2(t)\cos(t)]\\
|\dot z|=\sqrt{9[\cos^4(t)\sin^2(t)+\sin^4(t)\cos^2(t)]}=3\cos(t)\sin(t)
$$

Then

$$s=3\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(t)\sin(t)\ dt=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: My question wasn't to find examples in which the arclength can be computed, of which there are many examples. My question is equivalent to finding parametric curves that have constant velocity.

Comment: @ChristianBueno: Then you can just replace the limit of the integral with a parameter, can't you?