# Area of the surface from curve

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve $y=\cosh(4x)/4$, $-1\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ about the $x$-axis.

I setup the integral as:
$$2\pi\int_{-1}^{1}x\cdot \cosh(4x)/4dx$$

and ended up getting $0$ as the answer. Is that really the answer?

I also need to know how would one go about rotating this about the y-axis, but have no idea where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get this integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the surface areas due to rotation about either the $x$ or $y$ axes using Pappus's $(1^{st})$ Centroid Theorem, which states that the surface area A of a surface of revolution generated by rotating a plane curve C about an axis external to C and on the same plane is equal to the product of the arc length s of C and the distance d traveled by its geometric centroid ([Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)). Simply put, $S=2\pi RL$, where R is the normal distance of the centroid to the axis of revolution and $L$ is curve length. The centroid of a curve is given by

$$\mathbf{R}=\frac{\int \mathbf{r}ds}{\int ds}=\frac{1}{L} \int \mathbf{r}ds$$

Thus we can say for your cases that

$$
S=2\pi\int_{-1}^1 y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\ dx \text{  for rotation about the x-axis}\\
S=2\pi\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\ dx \text{  for rotation about the y-axis}
$$

Here, we notice that for rotation about the *y*-axis the integration limits are $x\in [0,1]$, since that is the only part of the curve that is being rotated.

Now, it seems that someone has carefully designed your problem to be tractable, because $$\sqrt{1+(y')^2}=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(4x)}=\cosh(4x)$$

I'll give you my final results (and I hope they are correct!).

$$
S=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[1+\frac{\sinh(8)}{8} \right] \text{  for rotation about the x-axis}\\
S=\frac{\pi}{8}[4\sinh(4)-\cosh(4)+1] \text{  for rotation about the y-axis}
$$

Let me know if you need any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the formula for the surface area in the case of a surface of revolution (e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html)).

The surface area of the surface obtained by rotation the graph of $y=f(x)$ about the $x$-axis on the interval $[x_1,x_2]$, is given by:
$$2\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2} y \sqrt{1+ \left(y'\right)^2}\,\mbox{d}x = 2\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \sqrt{1+ \left(f'(x)\right)^2}\,\mbox{d}x$$
Now if $f(x) = \tfrac{\cosh(4x)}{4}$, then $f'(x)=\sinh(4x)$ so rotation on $[-1,1]$ gives:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \cosh(4x) \sqrt{1+ \sinh^2(4x)}\,\mbox{d}x$$
You can simplify (a lot). Can you take it from here?

---

> I also need to know how would one go about rotating this about the y-axis, but have no idea where to start.

The [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) from above also covers the formula for rotation about the $y$-axis.