Finding or constructing Archimedes spirals with/from parametric lengths
I'm using Desmos, and have already combed through this site not finding anything close to what I need, nor have the equations and modifications I have tried been of help.
Desmos Trial by Combat
I need to either construct an Archimedes spiral from an adjustable amount of equal linear length segments, or use a slider to automatically mark a certain number of points that are each an equal predetermined length apart along the length of the spiral.
I do not understand calculus, and so would appreciate being taught like an idiot.

The closest thing I found is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81636/how-to-place-objects-equidistantly-on-an-archimedean-spiral , but I'm using Desmos not python, and I don't understand enough about what they said to port it over.

I figured out that I somehow need to nullify the rate of change that happens due to the angle with increasing radius,  but have not figured out how, nor how to apply that knowledge.
